# how do i access files i do not have permissions for?

Tags: 12.04, permissions

I am upgrading my desktop, and I transferred all my files to two hard drives. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a third drive, booted it up, and mounted the other two volumes. I try to access the files and it says I do not have permission and I think its because I was a different user on Ubuntu on the old computer. Pertinent information, music, and photos are on those drives and I need an answer an idiot could follow as I still do not understand terminal or command line.

```
/dev/sda: LABEL="storage volume 3" UUID="680aad74-1b4f-41aa-8cc1-55d5fa04f961" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="7b974307-86b3-4f3b-9f3a-d4ed922efbd2" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="4e845c4b-82a9-4191-9634-d58815d2f39a" TYPE="swap" 

Disk /dev/sda: 30.1 GB, 30060527616 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3654 cylinders, total 58711968 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sda doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdb: 20.0 GB, 20003880960 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2432 cylinders, total 39070080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000f11a2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048    35010559    17504256   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2        35012606    39069695     2028545    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5        35012608    39069695     2028544   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: provide some more info like the filesystem of the 2 volumes and the complete error. open the terminal and key in the following highlighted commands `sudo blkid` and `sudo fdisk -l`. you may edit your question and post the outputs.

Comment: i havent finished upgrading the hardware yet, but i am using a 20gb hdd of ubuntu 12.04 to try to load and copy all my data from two other hdd's to usb flash drive before i do my final build/install. the data on both hdd's were from a previous instal of the same ubuntu version but i believe it thinks im not the owner.

Comment: Your 20GB HDD has 3 partition which has linux installed. But your 30 GB HDD (/dev/sda) doesn't have a valid partition table. You need to have a partition in a HDD to mount and copy/save data. It's most probably corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the ownership using the following command:

```
sudo chown newusername.newusername -R /path_to_folder
```

then you should be able to access your old files.

Comment: am i supposed to type it exactly like that or do i have to substitute my drive/filename in that command?

Comment: Replace newusername with your current user name and /path_to_folder with the exact location of the folder. This is probably under /media/newusername if it is a portable drive.

Comment: can you give more detailed instructions on how to find that and how to do it? it is an actual hdd too. the name of the drive is:                  storage volume 3

Comment: If you navigate with nautilus (file explorer) to the folder location that you couldn't access and then you can press Control+L to see the exact location. You can copy (Control+C) & paste it then to the terminal by right clicking and selecting paste in the terminal. You have to type the first bit of the command I mentioned above.

Comment: @Harris , according to fdisk, /dev/sda doesn't have a valid partition table. how is nautilus going to mount it?

Comment: Good point. Cary mentioned that he couldn't access the folder and I assumed the partition was mounted successfully to get this message. It looks like there is a problem with the drive that needs to be solved first.

Comment: after completing those steps it says there is no such directory. could this mean i have the wrong drive? or that it has been corrupted and/or my data lost already? also, the only file listed in explorer is lost and found

Comment: Can you show us the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` only.

Comment: ok thank you guys very much. i finally found out that somehow my 30gb disk became corrupted. i tried to use gparted to find files and restore the partition but i ended up formatting anyway. however, the other drive which is an 80gb seagate the above help worked perfectly and i recovered the other 90 percent of my files! and i leaned a little more about linux.